# Make Angular Bootstrap UI date ascending

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap for my date dropdowns, which works great, except the year is descending (from the maximum year), is there a way to make it ascend from the current year instead?

Comment: As far as I know, the datepicker is initialized with whatever date you pass on to it through `ng-model` If you don't pass it a date, I think it defaults to the current date/month/year. Not sure what you mean by ascending order.

Comment: Actually it is not a 'date picker' like a calendar, but three drop downs (day/month/year).

Comment: Please provide some code showing how these dropdowns are populated.  it's clear that you are using `uib-dropdown` but not how you have bound your data.  It is likely that a filter can be applied to change the order of the data being presented in the dropdown, but seeing the code is necessary to verify this and demonstrate how it would be done.